# How to modified startTime in jQuery Timepicker?

Tags: jquery, timepicker, alpine.js

I have this HTML:

```
<p id="jampraktik" name="jampraktik" class="text-sm text-gray-600" x-text="dokter.jampraktik"></p>
```

I want to use the `x-text` value as startTime parameter for Timepicker's dropdown. Is it possible? `Console.log($('jampraktik').text()` will show result "19:00".

Hardcoded working fine as expected. But if i add `var jampraktik = $('#jampraktik').text();`, the dropdown start from 00:00 instead 19:00. Thank you.

This is my script:

```
<script>
var jampraktik = $('#jampraktik').text();
//var jampraktik = '19:00';

$('#pilihkedatangan').timepicker({
timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
startTime: jampraktik,                        
minTime: '09:00',
maxHour: 21,
interval: 15 // 15 minutes
});
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the JS in this example, you have to pass each time as DATE(0, 0, 0, HOURS, MINUTES, 0) https://jsfiddle.net/wvega/Gczvz/embedded/result,js,html,css,resources/

Comment: Take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/hajhamzah/u05bg2p1/3/ It worked as long as the text value not inside a loop. So maybe i should find a way to copy the text value from inside the loop, hidden it somewhere and then used it as a reference for startTime.